# Can I make Eclipse filter-out resources matched by .gitignore?

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

I'm importing some git repository as an Eclipse (CDT) project. I would like to have all resources which are matched by `.gitignore` filtered out of view - either dynamically, or by having resource filters created for them upon import. Is this possible?